# Why does Ivacy VPN turn off after a brief period of time?

Tags: networking, vpn

Running Ubuntu 19.10 on a Lenovo Flex-3-1570 (dual boot with Windows 10 Insider Preview). Ivacy has been installed as PPTP following previous option setups. When turned on, VPN icon appears on status bar. After a period of time when working with browser, VPN turns off and icon disappears.

Comment: I encountered similar issue with ivacy.com provider. You need to follow this old manual:
https://support.ivacy.com/setup_guide/how-to-setup-ivacy-pptp-protocol-manually-on-ubuntu/
But the username is not your e-mail, and rather some nonsense in format: ivacyxxxxxxxxx which you can find on their web.
Finally I have set "Use custom unit number" to 1 I hope this helps.

Comment: I did follow the instructions as set out in that document before this. Where is the "Use custom unit number" setting located?

Comment: Found custom unit number. Makes no difference. Still turns off. Does not do this in Win 10.

Answer (score 0):

After more research, found that the Firewall app was installed and active. Since Ivacy was not permitted to talk to servers, it would turn off after a period of time. Turning off the firewall allowed Ivacy to work as it should.